# VB.Net passing Hashtable and string to recursive procedure

Tags: vb.net, string, recursion, hashtable

Here I have a recursive procedure go. It seems that whenever the `Hashtable` is passed to the recursive procedure (`ByVal` or `ByRef`) it stays in memory even when exiting the procedure. The string stays in memory on each invocation of the procedure, but it goes away when exiting the procedure because it is passed `ByVal`. Are the two objects treated differently, or is my understanding off?

At the end of `form1_load`, why is ht.count always equal to 4 regardless of whether it was passed byref or byval?

I was thinking that ht.count and the length of str should always be the same since both are passed byval. Why is this not true?

Thank you for your help and trying to understand! Let me know if I need to be more clear.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ht As New Hashtable
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim str As String = ""
    go(ht, str, i)
    MsgBox("strLen = " & Len(str) & vbCrLf & "htCount = " & ht.Count)
End Sub
Private Sub go(ByVal ht As Hashtable, ByVal str As String, ByVal i As Integer)

    str = str & "0"
    ht.Add(i, 0)

    i = i + 1
    If i < 5 Then
        go(ht, str, i)
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit: I couldn't answer my own question because I'm new, so here is what i realized too:

For anybody that is wondering, I realized I was trying to understand the way a mutable object is passed to a procedure byref or byval. I added ht2, and the go procedure now just assignes ht to ht2.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ht As New Hashtable
    Dim ht2 As New Hashtable
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim str As String = ""
    go(ht, str, i, ht2)
    MsgBox("strLen = " & Len(str) & vbCrLf & "htCount = " & ht.Count & vbCrLf & "ht2Count = " & ht2.Count)
End Sub
Private Sub go(ByVal ht As Hashtable, ByVal str As String, ByVal i As Integer, ByVal ht2 As Hashtable)

    str = str & "0"
    ht.Add(i, 0)
    ht2 = ht

    i = i + 1
    If i < 5 Then
        go(ht, str, i, ht2)
    End If

End Sub
```

Now ht2 is dependent on the way it is passed to the procedure, and ht2.count should always be the same as the length of str. Also, this helped me understand: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These two objects are not treated differently. The problem is how you are using them. String concatenation does not change the String, it merely returns a new String with the concatenated value. Hashtable.Add(), however, does change the object.

The ByRef thing is a little harder to understand. String's ByRef behaves like you expect because you are changing the object that you are referencing. However, Hashtable's ByRef doesn't behave like you expect, because you are sending the table a message. Hashtable.Add tells the table: Add this into your collection. Hence, you are always dealing with the same object.

Thus, the difference here is that you are creating multiple copies of the String and changing references, but you only have one copy of the Hashtable and changing its contents.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. Also, I just realized that if I want the return of the hashtable to be dependent on the way it is passed to procedure, then i should build a new hashtable inside the recursive function and have this new one returned.

Answer (score 0):

`String`s and `HashTable`s are both reference types. The main difference in your case is their mutability.

`String`s are immutable. Whenever you "edit" a `String`, you are creating a new one, in a new memory location on the heap.

`HashTable`s are mutable, so when you add/remove an element, you aren't building a whole new `HashTable`. It stays where it was before on the heap.

Comment: Thanks! This acutally put me on the right track. I realized I was trying to relate the mutability of the hashtable with the way it is passed to the procedure.